# Как добавлять строчку вверх в tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Пытаюсь добавить новую строчку из сервера на вверх .Но почему то все добавляется вниз.У меня Сегмент контроль который разделен на 3 массива.Я  создал функцию добавления ячейки и вот мой код.Потом я функцию поместил в сегмент для обновления и Рефреш(обновления) .

```
func insertNewRow() {
        soccerString.append(Soccer())
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: soccerString.count-1, section: 0)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

это Сегмент для обновления массива :

```
@IBAction func btnSegment(_ sender: Any) {

        insertNewRow()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Это функция Refresh :

```
@objc func refreshing() {

    loadObjects1()
    loadObjects2()
    loadObjects3()
    insertNewRow()

    tableView.reloadData()
    refresh.endRefreshing()

}
```

Пожалуйста подскажите что я неправильно делаю.Отвечайте по делу, а не лиж бы как .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начало массива это 0 элемент, а

```
soccerString.append(Soccer())
```

это добавление в конец массива, так же и со строками у Вас.

Поэтому необходимо вставлять:

```
soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at: 0)
// строка tableView:
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скажите а tableView.beginUpdates() иt ableView.endUpdates() не нужно добавлять?

Comment: я добавил в  функцию viewDidLoad и Рефреш не идет добавление вверх.подскажите где искать ошибку, и у меня есть функция Parse где загружается массив.